# Some images do not render in the pdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I am currently using **codeigniter** as a framework.

I have a function that generates a pdf using **dompdf**. Inside the pdf I have an image when I try to load a certain png image it does not load it only shows

> "Image not found or type unknown."

But when I load a different png image it loads in the pdf without a problem.

Note: I have set this already: `$dompdf->set_option("isRemoteEnabled",true);`

please help me